# Auto fill login information in the website

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a password manager software with python where user can store username password and website. Our professor ask me to make the following feature:
If user click on visit website button the website will be opened in browser and the login information will be filled automatically.
I'm new to python and I couldn't find information how to build this feature. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [selenium library](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to open up a browser and fill in forms from python.